# Where to specify "use_natural_primary_keys" with generic class views?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I've been reading about natural_keys and have added the `get_by_natural_key()` and `natural_key()` methods to my model(s), but the Django docs (and several posts here in SO) say: "Then, when you call `serializers.serialize()`, you provide `use_natural_foreign_keys=True` or `use_natural_primary_keys=True` arguments" ...followed by this example:

```
>>> serializers.serialize('json', [book1, book2], indent=2,
...      use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)
```

But that example is from running in a python shell, not in the actual context of where to put it in code.  From DRF, I'm using generic class based views.  Where should I specify those arguments in that case?

**EDIT:** The ultimate goal is to be able to import fixtures using natural_keys instead of actual IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You would not do this at all. `serializers.serialize` is Django's built-in - and very basic - serialization functionality. But you are using DRF, which has much more powerful abilities to serialize. In DRF you would define your serializer to use [the relevant relational field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

**Edit** But I don't understand your edit at all. What do DRF's generic views have to do with fixtures?

Comment: From what I understand, if `loaddata` doesn't get an `"id": nnn` element in the fixture, it uses `get_by_natural_key()` instead. Have I already solved the `loaddata` issue by adding `get_by_natural_key()` to the model - meaning I don't need to worry about having it in the serializer?